# Forward and backward fill each group in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, group-by, missing-data

How to do forward and backward fill for each group in PySpark? For example, if we use the column `id` to group data and the column `order` to sort values with missing data:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('a', 1.0, 1.0),
    ('b', 1.0, 2.0),
    ('a', 2.0, float("nan")),
    ('b', 2.0, float("nan")),
    ('a', 3.0, 3.0),
    ('b', 3.0, 4.0)],
    ["id", "order", "values"])

+---+-----+------+
| id|order|values|
+---+-----+------+
|  a|  1.0|   1.0|
|  b|  1.0|   2.0|
|  a|  2.0|   NaN|
|  b|  2.0|   NaN|
|  a|  3.0|   3.0|
|  b|  3.0|   4.0|
+---+-----+------+
```

Expected result for forward fill:

```
+---+-----+------+
| id|order|values|
+---+-----+------+
|  a|  1.0|   1.0|
|  b|  1.0|   2.0|
|  a|  2.0|   1.0|
|  b|  2.0|   2.0|
|  a|  3.0|   3.0|
|  b|  3.0|   4.0|
+---+-----+------+
```

Expected result for backward fill:

```
+---+-----+------+
| id|order|values|
+---+-----+------+
|  a|  1.0|   1.0|
|  b|  1.0|   2.0|
|  a|  2.0|   3.0|
|  b|  2.0|   4.0|
|  a|  3.0|   3.0|
|  b|  3.0|   4.0|
+---+-----+------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `nan` values with `null`s first, then use `coalesce` combined with `last` and `first` functions (with *ignoreNulls* set to *true*) over windows like the example here :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

ffill_window = "(partition by id order by order rows between unbounded preceding and current row)"
bfill_window = "(partition by id order by order rows between current row and unbounded following)"

(df
 .withColumn("values", F.expr("case when isnan(values) then null else values end"))
 .withColumn("values_ffill", F.expr(f"coalesce(values, last(values, true) over {ffill_window})"))
 .withColumn("values_bfill", F.expr(f"coalesce(values, first(values, true) over {bfill_window})"))
).show()

# +---+-----+------+------------+------------+
# | id|order|values|values_ffill|values_bfill|
# +---+-----+------+------------+------------+
# |  b|  1.0|   2.0|         2.0|         2.0|
# |  b|  2.0|  null|         2.0|         4.0|
# |  b|  3.0|   4.0|         4.0|         4.0|
# |  a|  1.0|   1.0|         1.0|         1.0|
# |  a|  2.0|  null|         1.0|         3.0|
# |  a|  3.0|   3.0|         3.0|         3.0|
# +---+-----+------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: I tried to do this with `groupby` and `apply` of  `pandas_udf` to each group (or `applyInPandas`). Is it possible to do that in this way?

Comment: I don't quite understand how do you want to use `groupby` here, but I think you can use `pandas_udf` for this.

Comment: Something like `df.groupby('id).apply(pandas_udf_func)` or in PySpark 3.0 `df.groupby('id').applyInPandas(pandas_func)`